# What is C#.net meaning in conjuction with terms like Javascript, HTML5, CSS etc?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I recently got an offer for a traineeship for C#.NET. However before being allowed in the traineeship I need to make a small program which displays my programming skills in "C#.net". I don't know what to do now. I've downloaded visual studio 2015 and when I open it I see lots of stuff like console application/windows application etc and even .asp.net applications for web.

In the traineeship document terms are used like " Object Oriëntated, Object Orientated Analysis and Design, UML, Database Design, SQL, XML, Scrum, Javascript, HTML5 CSS3, jQuery, Ajax, Design Pattern (MVC) and WCF.

I don't have a clue where to start! If they wanted ASP websites they could've explicated this right? Should I make them a keygen music mp3 player in a console application? Srs please help. I got 1 week for this.

Comment: This is off topic as is, but those are essentially big words meaning that you should be able to take items used by the business and construct classes which represent them. You would also need to find a good way to store these objects in a database and use SQL to query said database. You would need to develop a web front end to access this data as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! What would your reaction be if I said this was some pretest before being allowed in the traineeship (duration of teachings is aproxx 8 weeks)

Comment: I'd inquire on the nature of the program am I supposed to be developing. `Are there some specifications I need to fulfil?` would be on top of my list.

Comment: You would be developing a program in "C#.net" which would display some programming talent. They did not say anything more about it unfortunately.

Comment: It never hurts to ask for more details where possible. Something along the lines of *Would it be possible to provide more information on the program I am to develop or am I to develop something of my choosing?*, or something like that. **Note though that you might have information acquired from previous contacts, in that case I'd recommend you act accordingly. Also note that this is not a career advice site, so responsability of the outcome rests solely on you**.

Comment: One week is not enough time to learn the concepts you mentioned if you don't already know them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when asked to perform such task with as vague description as possible, the recruiters want to see your creativity and general knowledge of the technology. You don't have write another Windows system, so it's entirely up to you on what you decide to write. Just make sure it will work and it will follow general coding guidelines and it should be okay :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is not the place to ask that question. You better go get some tutorials and try to walk your first steps on C# and .NET. As Keran said, the recruiters just want to know your programming and knowledge level of .NET.

Microsoft Virtual Academy is a good place to start.

Have fun!